# Facebook Marketing API for conversion statistics of individual targeted interests

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

Recently I've come across multiple third party apps that presumably integrate with the Facebook Marketing API that claim to be able to report on which individual targeted interests for ad sets are providing successful conversions.

E.g., an ad set targets 10 separate interests and gets 5x purchase conversions, they claim that they can tell you which of the 10 interests the conversions came from.

I spoke to Facebook support and asked them which API exposes this information, and they pointed me at their community Facebook groups.

Posting here in the hopes someone that's developed using the marketing API will be able to tell me which API call I need to make to get this info.

Third party app #1: https://connectio.io/ (ConnectExplore)

Third party app #2: https://interestexplorer.io/

I've been through the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis but I must be either missing it or these apps are getting the info from somewhere else?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created third party app #2: https://interestexplorer.io :)

That feature in the Ads API was called keyword_stats but has been deprecated by Facebook so there are not third party apps that c

Comment: Thanks Paco, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page, but it is in german...
[Facebook APi ADS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/)

Hopfully it will help you